# How can I get the contents of a file in dictionary using python?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, graph

I have a file whose contents are as below. It represents two junctions and its weight or distance.

```
a / b / 3
a / c / 5
a / d / 2
b / a / 3
b / e / 11
b / f / 12
c / a / 5
c / f / 7
d / a / 2
d / f / 8
d / g / 5
e / b / 11
e / f / 3
e / h / 3
f / b / 12
f / c / 7
f / d / 8
f / e / 3
f / g / 4
f / h / 7
f / i / 5
f / k / 4
g / d / 5
g / f / 4
g / k / 5
h / e / 3
h / f / 7
h / j / 2
i / f / 5
i / j / 3
j / h / 2
j / i / 3
j / k / 6
k / g / 5
k / f / 4
k / j / 6
```

I want to create a dictionary or rather a graph from the file which should look like below:

```
graph = {'a':{'b':3,'c':5,'d':2},'b':{'a':3,'e':11,'f':12},'c':{'a':5,'f':7},'d':{'a':2,'f':8,'g':5},'e':{'b':11,'f':3,'h':3},'f':{'b':12,'c':7,'d':8,'e':3,'g':4,'h':7,'i':5,'k':4},'g':{'d':5,'f':4,'k':5},'h':{'e':3,'f':7,'j':2},'i':{'f':5,'j':3} ,  'j':{'h':2,'i':3,'k':6}  ,'k':{'g':5,'f':4,'j':6}      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the file line by line replacing redundant space and prepared the desired dictionary with required key and values as:

```
res = dict()
with open('inp.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace(" ", "").rstrip()
        lst = line.split('/')
        
        if lst[0] in res.keys():
            res[lst[0]].update({lst[1]: int(lst[2])})
        else:
            res[lst[0]] = {lst[1]: int(lst[2])}
        
print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'b': 3, 'c': 5, 'd': 2}, 'b': {'a': 3, 'e': 11, 'f': 12}, 'c': {'a': 5, 'f': 7}, 'd': {'a': 2, 'f': 8, 'g': 5}, 'e': {'b': 11, 'f': 3, 'h': 3}, 'f': {'b': 12, 'c': 7}}
```

Note: I have only taken a subset of data for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the file, line by line, splitting on `/` and adding to a dictionary called `graph`.  The key here is to create a `defaultdict` object to hold the data in order to avoid a `KeyError`.  I would do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

input_file = sys.argv[1]

graph = defaultdict(dict)

with open(input_file) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        elems = line.rstrip('\n').split(' / ')
        graph[elems[0]].update({elems[1] : int(elems[2])})
```

That will result in:

```
{'a': {'b': '3', 'c': '5', 'd': '2'},
 'b': {'a': '3', 'e': '11', 'f': '12'},
 'c': {'a': '5', 'f': '7'},
 'd': {'a': '2', 'f': '8', 'g': '5'},
 'e': {'b': '11', 'f': '3', 'h': '3'},
 'f': {'b': '12',
       'c': '7',
       'd': '8',
       'e': '3',
       'g': '4',
       'h': '7',
       'i': '5',
       'k': '4'},
 'g': {'d': '5', 'f': '4', 'k': '5'},
 'h': {'e': '3', 'f': '7', 'j': '2'},
 'i': {'f': '5', 'j': '3'},
 'j': {'h': '2', 'i': '3', 'k': '6'},
 'k': {'f': '4', 'g': '5', 'j': '6'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, the numbers will be treated as string? How can we treat them as an integer.

Comment: You can cast them to an integer with the `int()` method.  I've updated the code to set the numbers as integers instead of strings.